# KIWI TCMS remove HTTPS and go to HTTP in Docker

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have a docker container, how can I most easily remove 443 and go to port 80 from Kiwi web.

I don't see anywhere a configuration file in the docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the following lines from `/etc/kiwi-httpd.conf` in the kiwi repository and then recreated the docker image:

```
# Force the use of ssl:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

Then Kiwi won't try to redirect to https anymore, so I can handle the SSL certificate myself before I proxy on to Kiwi.

Just note that absolute links to Kiwi itself that Kiwi generates, for example links in the emails Kiwi sends out, will be `http`. Most of the time this shouldn't be a problem if you redirect to the same URL with `https`, but it could potentially be a problem in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't disable HTTPS and we are not going to allow you to do this because it is a bad idea and people will start deploying without https in production.

Just accept the self signed certificate (or supply your own certificate) and that should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible, as it should be. Traffic can be encrypted not directly but before that. I did by editing the configuration file in kiwi-web - web server httpd settings in /etc/